# VBA Combobox Item Separator

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, list-separator

I am trying to insert a simple item separator (horizontal line) in my combobox which cannot be selected and is there just for the design - separating groups of combobox items.

I have browsed some answers, yet none of them actually gave the finite answer (whether it is or it is not possible).

Anyone had a chance to implement anything like this? I can surely add new item with the following text "---------------" but I am keeping it as a plan B.

Comment: Plan B is the way to go: you will need to add code to make it un-selectable.  Eg: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=47646

Comment: I would say you can either go with plan B and implement code to make the horizontal lines unselectable OR you need to break your comboboxes into multiple comboboxes and have the latter comboboxes populate based on prior selections, essentially splitting the divided areas out into their own comboboxes.